# Is it possible to have array as an argument to INDIRECT(), so INDIRECT() returns array?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Suppose, that I have a vector of cells `A1:A5`, each with string that is an address of the other cell.

What I want to do, is to have a function, that returns *an array of values from these referenced cells*. See the example - I want the formula to return 15 (it returns 1).

[image]

In production setting, this vector is much longer (ca. 2000 rows).

What would solve the problem, is array-capable INDIRECT().

(I realize, that I might be pushing Excel beyond its the limits)...

---

My further thoughts on this topic:

Because the INDIRECT() is capable of producing arrays even from a single-cell input, such theoretical "INDIRECTARR()" formula would either require nested (i.e. multidimensional) array computation support in Excel, or will be intrinsically limited to arguments that denote one-dimensional ranges.

Comment: I don't think that `INDIRECT` can take arrays. It even returns `#VALUE!` 5 times when `SUMPRODUCT` is used instead of `SUM` (which yields to 0 by the way) =/

Comment: @Jerry I'm open to suggestions how to replace this example with other functions.

Comment: I don't know your exact values (the complexity of the references, but for your example, you could do something like `=SUM(INDIRECT(A1&":"&A5))`

Comment: @Jerry Thank you for a good answer. Yes, that will work if the B1:B5 are actually in one row. In my setup they aren't. My illustration is really misleading, I'll update it now. You can see a related problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19788361/how-to-make-nested-array-computations-with-index

Answer (score 3):

Finally I've found a way to solve it. As long as the values are on one sheet, we can take advantage of the fact, that when the second and/or the third argument to INDEX is an array, the result is an array as well:

[image]

It is a bit hackish, but it certainly works and doesn't need any VBA nor addons. And it is fast.

Comment: Hmm, I've copied your example sheet exactly, but with that formula (using ctrl+shift+escape when entering), I still get a sum of 1 (or whatever is in B1).  
Any advice? I'm a relative Excel newbie so I may well be doing something wrong.

Comment: @exscape It is an array formula. Did you press ctrl+shift+enter after typing it in?

Comment: Yep, I did (though I said escape in my previous comment, I did mean enter).

Comment: @exscape You are right; I also get "1". But if you omit the SUM function, you still get a proper array formula, that can display the consecutive 1,2,3,4,5 numbers... Weird, because I am pretty sure, that the sum used to work.

Comment: I have un-accepted my answer, since it is misleading. I tried to fiddle a little, but I couldn't find a solution. The way INDEX handles (array) formulas with arrays in second and/or third argument is a little strange.

Comment: I posted a very similar question to Superuser, and got an answer that solved the issue. In short, use =SUM(SUM(INDIRECT(A1:A5)) as an array formula (i.e. use Ctrl+Shift+Enter), and the sum shows up as 15. :-)
Link: https://superuser.com/questions/1196243/simplify-a-sum-of-indirect-cell-values