# How to make nested array computations with INDEX()?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Imagine I have several (i.e. > 100) column vectors of numbers. Vectors are large with equal length (e.g. 20k items). The vectors are not adjacent, so they don't make a matrix.

What I want, is to get some row-wise computation with the vectors, for instance

*For each row what is the first non zero value among all vectors?*

or

*For each row what is the maximal value among all vectors?*

See this simplified example, that should get the maximal value for all vectors, which would be 3 for all row (in reality the displayed value is 1):

[image]

It would be easy, if I could copy the vectors as a matrix and get the column of row ranges that spans all vectors for a given row, instead of the column ranges. But that is not the option due to the size of the data. I think it is related to other SO question: [Is it possible to have array as an argument to INDIRECT(), so INDIRECT() returns array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19787285/is-it-possible-to-have-array-as-an-argument-to-indirect-so-indirect-returns).

Comment: Any interest in a VBA solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CHOOSE to combine equal sized columns into a single range, e.g. for your 3 range example:

`=CHOOSE({1,2,3},$B$1:$B$4,$B$5:$B$8,$A$3:$A$6)`

Then use that directly in a formula, e.g. in G2 copied down to get the MAX in each row for your example

`=MAX(INDEX(CHOOSE({1,2,3},$B$1:$B$4,$B$5:$B$8,$A$3:$A$6),F2,0))`

or you can define the CHOOSE part as a named range [especially useful if you have 100 ranges], e.g. name that Matrix and use

`=MAX(INDEX(Matrix,F2,0))`

You need to modify the {1,2,3} part based on the number of ranges, to shortcut when you have 100 ranges you can use

`=CHOOSE(TRANSPOSE(ROW(INDIRECT("1:100"))),Range1, Range2.....Range100)`

Now needs to be confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

To get the first non-zero value you can use this version

`=INDEX(INDEX(Matrix,F2,0),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(Matrix,F2,0)<>0,0))`

also confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Comment: You are a real houdini to me! Its so fascinating and refreshing to find such bright minds on the SO! I've learned a lot today, thanks to you!

Comment: I think I will start using two-dimensional array formulas on every worksheet I can.

Comment: Is there any chance of having the idiom `CHOOSE({1,2,3},$B$1:$B$4,$B$5:$B$8,$A$3:$A$6)` to work with indirect ranges, like this: `CHOOSE({1,2,3},INDIRECT(Z1),INDIRECT(Z2),INDIRECT(Z3))`? It is strange, that the second form works well if pasted directly into worksheet, but fails to work when pasted as a named range...

Answer (score -1):

I've found that you actually "can" return an array from `INDIRECT()`.

However it must be in `"R1C1"` syntax AND you cannot create your R1C1 syntax with a formula (not with something like `"R" & ROW() & "C" & COLUMN()"`.

You have to enter the ROW & COLUMN numbers as absolute and then it works.

Apparently excel puts `{}` around the numbers when they are returned by `ROW()` or `COLUMN()` function, and I guess that's why it doesn't work (try debugging, you'll see).

Comment: It wasn't me, who downvoted your answer, but I believe your post answers the question I stated in the comment section of the barry houdini's answer, so it should have been posted as an additional comment there, not as formal answer. Unless you have 1 point of reputation, and you cannot post comments. Which in this case as a catch-42 for you. SO is not a forum and is very serious with the policy of posts being strictly an answer to the question.